# Substring from string and convert to json object in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex

I have a string like

> This {manish } {abc} {123 } is my string CopyResult={ Region : us-west-2, AmiId : ami-0f60f66f},{ Region : us-west-1, AmiId : ami-2884de48}, manish kumar

I want to get the sub-string like

```
{ Region : us-west-2, AmiId : ami-0f60f66f},{ Region : us-west-1, AmiId : ami-2884de48}
```

After getting that I want to convert that string to JSON.

I am trying code like

```
 var pt = /CopyResult=.*/;
 var copyAmisResult = copyAmilog.match(pt);
 console.log("copyAmilog -- " + copyAmisResult);
```

Output

> CopyResult={ Region : us-west-2, AmiId : ami-0f60f66f},{ Region : us-west-1, AmiId : ami-2884de48},

Could some one please suggest me the modified regular expression so that I can get my output.

PS:-  I need to remove `CopyResult=` from begning of the string and `,` from last of the string and also it can have multiple `{}`. After that is there an easier way to convert that string to JSON object. Could JSON.parse() be useful?

Comment: I'm no good with regex but JSON.parse() will be useful once you get the string `JSON.parse('[' + '{"one": 1}, {"two": 2}, {"three": 3}' + ']');` just noticed that your variable names and values aren't wrapped in quotes, need to do that too..

Comment: You should tell your server to return proper JSON instead of doing this hack job.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer it's very hard to get the JSON result in my case. so I don't have option.

Comment: why down vote could you please explain so that i can improve the question

Comment: It's pretty ugly with the big .replace chain and might be too fragile but here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/sgL1fmsL/ (using Ratan's regex -- ty!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to get the substring you want, but i'm not sure how to convert it to an object

```js
var str = "This {manish } {abc} {123 } is my stringCopyResult={ Region : us-west-2, AmiId : ami-0f60f66f},{ Region : us-west-1, AmiId : ami-2884de48}, manish kumar";
console.log( str.match(/=\s*({.*})/)[1]);
```

Comment: what if multiple {} be there ? I have updated my question.

Comment: str.match(/stringCopyResult={.*}/)[0].slice("stringCopyResult=".length)          you can use this right?

Comment: I've updated it to match for the "=" before it, but it will fail if there "={" that you don't want to catch. You should specify exactly how you want to capture to get the right regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data as follow.

```js
var copyAmilog = 'This {manish } {abc} {123 } is my stringCopyResult={ Region : us-west-2, AmiId : ami-0f60f66f},{ Region : us-west-1, AmiId : ami-2884de48}, manish kumar'
var pt = /stringCopyResult=(.*),/;
var copyAmisResult = copyAmilog.match(pt);
console.log("copyAmilog -- " , copyAmisResult[1]);
```